# Can I create an ArrayBuffer or Float32Array from 2 underlying buffers?

Tags: javascript

Instead of allocating a new JavaScript ArrayBuffer of the size data1size + data2size can I create a ArrayBuffer's that has two underlying buffers and intelligently iterate over them?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing this in Node?

Maybe [`Buffer.concat(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) is what you are looking for?

Comment: That class is alright. The ```ArrayBuffer``` i was referring to was the original JavaScript buffer which is the underlying data storage or ```TypedArrays``` like ```Float32Array```. I am tryinto to avoid a re-allocation + copy.

Comment: Just realized my description was not so accurate. So I edited it